# Can't make migration UWP SQLite EF

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, uwp

Hello i was following the tutorial on https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/03/data-access-in-universal-windows-platform-uwp-apps/

but i've got issue while migrating my db.

I tried to search in google, but the only solution i found was to upgrade EF, but i've got all up to date.
Error:

> PM> Add-Migration MyFirstMigration
>   System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.LogVerbose(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger, System.String)'.
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.OperationExecutor.d__7.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass4_0`1.b__0()
>      at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>   **Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerExtensions.LogVerbose(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger, System.String)'.**

What should i do now?

Comment: @Bart 
Not rly, but maybe i do sth wrong in my entity model.http://imgur.com/idEV1uA

Comment: Than this is weird. Can you upload somewhere this solution?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have done something wrong alone the way. I've copied over your model and DbContext and followed the [official docs](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/uwp/getting-started.html), which drills down to following commands:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite –Pre
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools –Pre
Add-Migration MyFirstMigration
```

I've uploaded my working sample to [GitHub](https://github.com/bartlannoeye/SO-Dump/tree/master/20160522%20-%20EF).

Comment: Seems that i have not up to date Vs. I've just updated, and still not up to date. Maybe i should just reinstall because sth went wrong here